# Using Jersey Test Framework to target APIs in other files

Tags: api, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have read [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) concerning the Jersey Test framework and have successfully used JerseyTest's target method to reach a @Path annotated endpoint within my own file. Simplified code is below.

```
public class TestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public TestApplication() {
        registerClasses(TestService.class);
    }
}

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new TestApplication();
}

@Path("create")
public static class TestService {
    @POST
    @Path("testObj")
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static Response createTestObj(final TestObj testObj) {
        return Response.ok("testObj created").build();
    }
}

@Test
private void ensureObjectCreated() {
    JSONObject myObj = createNewObj();
    final Response response = target("create/testObj").request(APPLICATION_JSON)
                              .post(Entity.json(myObj.toString()));
    Assert.isEqual(response.status, 200);
}
```

Now I want to reach a @Path annotated endpoint in other files/directories. How do I do so? The problem may be that the other files are actual production code, so I cannot make the classes static. However the endpoints in the other paths are reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just register them in the resource config, either individually (depending on the scope of the test), or specify a package to scan with the `packages` method.

```
@Override
public ResourceConfig configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig()
        .register(SomeResource.class)
        .packages("your.resource.package.to.scan");
}
```

The only reason the class in the example is `static` is because it is an inner class that needs to be instantiated by the framework.

When you access the resource, it will not include the root application path, only the `@Path` value on the class, and whatever sub path, just like in your code above.

Comment: I will try this and accept your answer if it works. Thank you so much